# Is this sentence correct in grammar?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

> This is the second time I came to America for.

As for the above sentence, is the preposition 'for' is necessary? In my opinion, the sentence should be revised to **'This is the second time that I have been to America.'** or **'This is the second time I came to America.'**

But my teacher told me that 'for' is necessary otherwise the sentence is incorrect. Is that right?

Comment: English teacher?  Are you sure your teacher said that?  "This is the second time I came to America for." is nonsense.

Comment: Yes, this is just for teaching the sentence structure, so there is no discourse.

Answer (score 1):

Well that depends, if you went to America for a purpose then yes you need a *for* as in "This is the second time I came to America for undisclosed reasons". But by itself it is not grammatically correct whereas both the examples you gave work as standalone sentences although I would prefer you say "This is the second time I HAVE COME to America" instead of "This is the second time I CAME to America".

Comment: So, if we don't consider the context, the preposition 'for' is redundant. Is that right?

Comment: It’s not redundant. It’s just nonsense. It’s an extra word. It only makes sense if something comes after it.  This answer from Quippy doesn’t make that clear.

Comment: @HenryWang I should add that english sentences generally don't end with prepositions so you should always be on the lookout for that

Answer (score 1):

> This is the second time I came to America for.

is incorrect. If "for" expressed a purpose it could appear "stranded" at the end of the sentence in this way, e.g.

> This is the second **wedding** I came to America for.

But when "for" occurs with "the first/second/third/... time", the preposition has to come first. The "for" is optional in this context, thus the following are fine:

> I came to America (for) the second time.
>
> This is the second time I came to America.

Answer (score 0):

The use of the preposition "for" at the end of the sentence is incorrect.  It has no complement.  A preposition phrase requires a complement.

The past tense "came" is acceptable, but in British English the present perfect would be better: there is a clear link to the present:

> This is the second time that I've come to London.

I'm not certain if AmE speakers would prefer present-perfect in that context.